# Scala Spark Sql - Reading null values from a Hive row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have a hive table `table_1` with the following schema

```
field_1 string
field_2 string
field_3 
  - field_3_1 string
  - field_3_2 double (nullable)
```

When I have an entry with the following values

```
field_1: "100"
field_2: "name"
field_3: 
  - field_3_1: "category_1"
  - field_3_2: null
```

I am trying to read this value from Scala as follows

```
sparkSession.sql("select field_1, field_3 from table_1 where field_1 ='100'").na
      .fill(new lang.Double(0), Seq("field_3.field_3_2")).foreach { r =>
          println(r)
    }
```

And I keep running into this error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

I don't control how the values get populated in the hive table. I am finding pretty difficult to move past this error even with wide searching of the web. Maybe I missed some clue somewhere. Can someone help with this? Thanks

Comment: Turns out the issue was with `json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies`, replaced it with version `1.3.8` and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your code correctly, u want to replace nulls of field_3.field_3_2 to zero value, right?

I tried to simulate it but i am not getting this error (altaugh it doesn`t fill me with zeros), maybe you should try this one:

```
spark.sql("select field_1, field_3 from table_1")
        .withColumn("field_3.field_3_2",when(col("field_3.field_3_2").isNull(),lit(0)).otherwise(col("field_3.field_3_2")))
```

it`ll replace nulls at zero (and if the field is NotNull it will keep the original value).

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

Turns out the issue was with `json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies`, replaced it with version `1.3.8` and that fixed it.